# Need to search a content which is in greek letters using strtoupper and strtolower

Tags: php

I am currently working in a GREEK project. In that project all the contents are GREEK and in that i have a search functionality. Search process is good. But strtoupper() didn't convert the Greek language to upper case and strtolower() didn't convert the Greek language to lower case.

But for English language its working fine. Is there any possible way to convert the Greek letters to UPPER and LOWER case.

thanks

Fero

Comment: You don't necessarily have to convert the needle/haystack to upper-case to make the search case-insensitive. There are functions that ignore the case _and_ can handle various code pages/unicode, e.g. http://docs.php.net/function.mb-stripos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no reason `mb_strtolower()` and `mb_strtoupper()` shouldn't work:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo mb_strtoupper('παπακωνσταντινου', 'UTF-8'); // ΠΑΠΑΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΥ
echo mb_strtolower('ΠΑΠΑΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΥ', 'UTF-8'); // παπακωνσταντινου

?>
```

**Using `mb_convert_case()` is another option, specially if you want to mimic `ucwords()`:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo mb_convert_case('παπακωνσταντινου', MB_CASE_UPPER, 'UTF-8'); // ΠΑΠΑΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΥ
echo mb_convert_case('ΠΑΠΑΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΥ', MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8'); // παπακωνσταντινου
echo mb_convert_case('παπακωνσταντινου', MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8'); // Παπακωνσταντινου

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about trying these functions:

```
mb_strtoupper
mb_strtolower
```

Comment: Sarfraz.. It didn't work.. I get some kind of special characters when i "echo" it. And even i didn't get any result

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mb_StrToUpper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) and [Mb_StrToLower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

They are a part of the [Multibyte String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), that can work with multibyte character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mb_strtoupper()`](http://bg.php.net/mb_strtoupper) and [`mb_strtolower()`](http://bg.php.net/mb_strtolower).

Answer (score 0):

$str = 'παπακωνσταντινου';

$test =  mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");

This is the correct syntax.

thanks all guys